# Eval code seems suspicious but without it my wordpress slider does not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security

Does anyone know what this code means?

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}(';(7($){$.w.Y=7(6){2(!5.F){B(\'Y: 3O z 3D - 3Q 3t 1w\');8 5}2(Q 6==\'7\'){6={O:6}}3 V=5.14(\'V\');3 I=(Q V===\'39\')?$.3x(V):\'\';2(I){I=(I.3y(/^([^#]+)/)||[])[1]}I=I||N.1O.1U||\'\';6=$.2J(12,{I:I,m:5[0].2k(\'2g\')||\'2D\',1E:/^3M/i.32(N.1O.1U||\'\')?\'38:K\':\'4a:47\'},6);3 18={};5.L(\'4-1n-2F\',[5,6,18]);2(18.18){B(\'Y: z 2z 1B 4-1n-2F L\');8 5}2(6.2x&&6.2x(5,6)===K){B(\'Y: z P 1B 2x 23\');8 5}3 n,v,a=5.2a(6.15);2(6.d){6.R=6.d;S(n 2w 6.d){2(6.d[n]42 1l){S(3 k 2w 6.d[n]){a.A({l:n,r:6.d[n][k]})}}p{v=6.d[n];v=$.3Z(v)?v():v;a.A({l:n,r:v})}}}2(6.2s&&6.2s(a,5,6)===K){B(\'Y: z P 1B 2s 23\');8 5}5.L(\'4-z-2y\',[a,5,6,18]);2(18.18){B(\'Y: z 2z 1B 4-z-2y L\');8 5}3 q=$.2e(a);2(6.m.3Y()==\'2D\'){6.I+=(6.I.1M(\'?\')>=0?\'&\':\'?\')+q;6.d=C}p{6.d=q}3 $4=5,1b=[];2(6.2u){1b.A(7(){$4.2u()})}2(6.2j){1b.A(7(){$4.2j()})}2(!6.1m&&6.D){3 2B=6.O||7(){};1b.A(7(d){3 w=6.3T?\'3S\':\'3U\';$(6.D)[w](d).1d(2B,3m)})}p 2(6.O){1b.A(6.O)}6.O=7(d,29,9){3 J=6.J||6;S(3 i=0,M=1b.F;i<M;i++){1b[i].3W(J,[d,29,9||$4,$4])}};3 31=$(\'E:44\',5).F>0;3 20=\'1p/4-d\';3 1p=($4.14(\'2I\')==20||$4.14(\'2H\')==20);2(6.2l!==K&&(31||6.2l||1p)){2(6.2S){$.45(6.2S,2o)}p{2o()}}p{$.4d(6)}5.L(\'4-z-4g\',[5,6]);8 5;7 2o(){3 4=$4[0];2($(\':E[l=z],:E[U=z]\',4).F){4c(\'4b: 46 2v 48 1D 3R l 4i U 3z "z".\');8}3 s=$.2J(12,{},$.3w,6);s.J=s.J||s;3 U=\'3C\'+(2b 3v().3s()),w=\'3u\'+U;3 $u=$(\'<2l U="\'+U+\'" l="\'+U+\'" 2Q="\'+s.1E+\'" />\');3 u=$u[0];$u.3r({3B:\'3L\',3i:\'-2L\',3c:\'-2L\'});3 9={P:0,W:C,1i:C,29:0,3K:\'n/a\',3J:7(){},2p:7(){},3F:7(){},3E:7(){B(\'3G 2C...\');3 e=\'P\';5.P=1;$u.14(\'2Q\',s.1E);9.H=e;s.H&&s.H.17(s.J,9,\'H\',e);g&&$.19.L("2E",[9,s,e]);s.1I&&s.1I.17(s.J,9,\'H\')}};3 g=s.2N;2(g&&!$.2t++){$.19.L("3H")}2(g){$.19.L("3I",[9,s])}2(s.2O&&s.2O.17(s.J,9,s)===K){2(s.2N){$.2t--}8}2(9.P){8}3 1S=0;3 1f=4.T;2(1f){3 n=1f.l;2(n&&!1f.1y){s.R=s.R||{};s.R[n]=1f.r;2(1f.m=="1g"){s.R[n+\'.x\']=4.1a;s.R[n+\'.y\']=4.16}}}7 27(){3 t=$4.14(\'D\'),a=$4.14(\'V\');4.1s(\'D\',U);2(4.2k(\'2g\')!=\'2P\'){4.1s(\'2g\',\'2P\')}2(4.2k(\'V\')!=s.I){4.1s(\'V\',s.I)}2(!s.4W){$4.14({2H:\'1p/4-d\',2I:\'1p/4-d\'})}2(s.1R){1t(7(){1S=12;1e()},s.1R)}3 2r=[];2G{2(s.R){S(3 n 2w s.R){2r.A($(\'<E m="4R" l="\'+n+\'" r="\'+s.R[n]+\'" />\').2K(4)[0])}}$u.2K(\'1h\');u.2R?u.2R(\'2i\',1e):u.4O(\'2T\',1e,K);4.z()}4P{4.1s(\'V\',a);2(t){4.1s(\'D\',t)}p{$4.4X(\'D\')}$(2r).2A()}}2(s.53){27()}p{1t(27,10)}3 d,h,2U=50;7 1e(){2(9.P){8}3 h=u.2Z?u.2Z.2Y:u.30?u.30:u.2Y;2(!h||h.1O.1U==s.1E){8}u.2X?u.2X(\'2i\',1e):u.4Q(\'2T\',1e,K);3 1o=12;2G{2(1S){4s\'1R\'}3 1z=s.1m==\'11\'||h.25||$.4u(h);B(\'1z=\'+1z);2(!1z&&N.1L&&(h.1h==C||h.1h.1J==\'\')){2(--2U){B(\'4M 4v 23, 1P 1D 4r\');1t(1e,4l);8}}9.W=h.1h?h.1h.1J:h.1q?h.1q.1J:C;9.1i=h.25?h.25:h;9.2p=7(2W){3 2V={\'33-m\':s.1m};8 2V[2W]};3 1Z=/(1T|3a)/.32(s.1m);2(1Z||s.1H){3 1Y=h.1C(\'1H\')[0];2(1Y){9.W=1Y.r}p 2(1Z){3 1n=h.1C(\'1n\')[0];3 b=h.1C(\'1h\')[0];2(1n){9.W=1n.4o}p 2(b){9.W=b.1J}}}p 2(s.1m==\'11\'&&!9.1i&&9.W!=C){9.1i=2M(9.W)}d=3n(9,s.1m,s)}4x(e){B(\'H 4y:\',e);1o=K;9.H=e;s.H&&s.H.17(s.J,9,\'H\',e);g&&$.19.L("2E",[9,s,e])}2(9.P){B(\'2C P\');1o=K}2(1o){s.O&&s.O.17(s.J,d,\'O\',9);g&&$.19.L("4G",[9,s])}g&&$.19.L("4I",[9,s]);2(g&&!--$.2t){$.19.L("4F")}s.1I&&s.1I.17(s.J,9,1o?\'O\':\'H\');1t(7(){$u.4B(\'4-1u-2i\');$u.2A();9.1i=C},3g)}3 2M=$.4S||7(s,h){2(N.3p){h=2b 3p(\'4D.4C\');h.4z=\'K\';h.4A(s)}p{h=(2b 4E()).4K(s,\'28/11\')}8(h&&h.1q&&h.1q.3q!=\'1X\')?h:C};3 1V=$.1V||7(s){8 N[\'4J\'](\'(\'+s+\')\')};3 3n=7(9,m,s){3 1K=9.2p(\'33-m\')||\'\',11=m===\'11\'||!m&&1K.1M(\'11\')>=0,d=11?9.1i:9.W;2(11&&d.1q.3q===\'1X\'){$.H&&$.H(\'1X\')}2(s&&s.3k){d=s.3k(d,m)}2(Q d===\'39\'){2(m===\'1T\'||!m&&1K.1M(\'1T\')>=0){d=1V(d)}p 2(m==="3a"||!m&&1K.1M("38")>=0){$.4p(d)}}8 d}}};$.w.22=7(6){2(5.F===0){3 o={s:5.34,c:5.J};2(!$.3l&&o.s){B(\'1P 1D 35, 4n 22\');$(7(){$(o.s,o.c).22(6)});8 5}B(\'4m; 4k 2v 4q 4w 34\'+($.3l?\'\':\' (1P 1D 35)\'));8 5}8 5.3d().36(\'z.4-1u\',7(e){2(!e.4t()){e.4L();$(5).Y(6)}}).36(\'3e.4-1u\',7(e){3 D=e.D;3 $f=$(D);2(!($f.54(":z,E:1g"))){3 t=$f.52(\':z\');2(t.F==0){8}D=t[0]}3 4=5;4.T=D;2(D.m==\'1g\'){2(e.3b!=1c){4.1a=e.3b;4.16=e.51}p 2(Q $.w.1r==\'7\'){3 1r=$f.1r();4.1a=e.3j-1r.3c;4.16=e.3h-1r.3i}p{4.1a=e.3j-D.4Z;4.16=e.3h-D.4Y}}1t(7(){4.T=4.1a=4.16=C},3g)})};$.w.3d=7(){8 5.4N(\'z.4-1u 3e.4-1u\')};$.w.2a=7(15){3 a=[];2(5.F===0){8 a}3 4=5[0];3 1A=15?4.1C(\'*\'):4.2v;2(!1A){8 a}3 i,j,n,v,f,M,2m;S(i=0,M=1A.F;i<M;i++){f=1A[i];n=f.l;2(!n){2f}2(15&&4.T&&f.m=="1g"){2(!f.1y&&4.T==f){a.A({l:n,r:$(f).13()});a.A({l:n+\'.x\',r:4.1a},{l:n+\'.y\',r:4.16})}2f}v=$.1v(f,12);2(v&&v.1N==1l){S(j=0,2m=v.F;j<2m;j++){a.A({l:n,r:v[j]})}}p 2(v!==C&&Q v!=\'1c\'){a.A({l:n,r:v})}}2(!15&&4.T){3 $E=$(4.T),E=$E[0];n=E.l;2(n&&!E.1y&&E.m==\'1g\'){a.A({l:n,r:$E.13()});a.A({l:n+\'.x\',r:4.1a},{l:n+\'.y\',r:4.16})}}8 a};$.w.4j=7(15){8 $.2e(5.2a(15))};$.w.4V=7(X){3 a=[];5.1d(7(){3 n=5.l;2(!n){8}3 v=$.1v(5,X);2(v&&v.1N==1l){S(3 i=0,M=v.F;i<M;i++){a.A({l:n,r:v[i]})}}p 2(v!==C&&Q v!=\'1c\'){a.A({l:5.l,r:v})}});8 $.2e(a)};$.w.1v=7(X){S(3 13=[],i=0,M=5.F;i<M;i++){3 f=5[i];3 v=$.1v(f,X);2(v===C||Q v==\'1c\'||(v.1N==1l&&!v.F)){2f}v.1N==1l?$.4U(13,v):13.A(v)}8 13};$.1v=7(f,X){3 n=f.l,t=f.m,1k=f.1W.2q();2(X===1c){X=12}2(X&&(!n||f.1y||t==\'1x\'||t==\'4T\'||(t==\'24\'||t==\'26\')&&!f.21||(t==\'z\'||t==\'1g\')&&f.4&&f.4.T!=f||1k==\'G\'&&f.2d==-1)){8 C}2(1k==\'G\'){3 1G=f.2d;2(1G<0){8 C}3 a=[],1Q=f.6;3 1j=(t==\'G-1j\');3 M=(1j?1G+1:1Q.F);S(3 i=(1j?1G:0);i<M;i++){3 Z=1Q[i];2(Z.1w){3 v=Z.r;2(!v){v=(Z.2n&&Z.2n[\'r\']&&!(Z.2n[\'r\'].4f))?Z.28:Z.r}2(1j){8 v}a.A(v)}}8 a}8 $(f).13()};$.w.2j=7(){8 5.1d(7(){$(\'E,G,1H\',5).3f()})};$.w.3f=$.w.3P=7(){8 5.1d(7(){3 t=5.m,1k=5.1W.2q();2(t==\'28\'||t==\'3N\'||1k==\'1H\'){5.r=\'\'}p 2(t==\'24\'||t==\'26\'){5.21=K}p 2(1k==\'G\'){5.2d=-1}})};$.w.2u=7(){8 5.1d(7(){2(Q 5.1x==\'7\'||(Q 5.1x==\'3A\'&&!5.1x.4h)){5.1x()}})};$.w.4e=7(b){2(b===1c){b=12}8 5.1d(7(){5.1y=!b})};$.w.1w=7(G){2(G===1c){G=12}8 5.1d(7(){3 t=5.m;2(t==\'24\'||t==\'26\'){5.21=G}p 2(5.1W.2q()==\'37\'){3 $1F=$(5).3V(\'G\');2(G&&$1F[0]&&$1F[0].m==\'G-1j\'){$1F.3X(\'37\').1w(K)}5.1w=G}})};7 B(){2($.w.Y.43){3 2h=\'[41.4] \'+1l.40.49.17(3m,\'\');2(N.2c&&N.2c.B){N.2c.B(2h)}p 2(N.1L&&N.1L.3o){N.1L.3o(2h)}}}})(4H);',62,315,'||if|var|form|this|options|function|return|xhr||||data||el||doc||||name|type|||else||value|||io||fn|||submit|push|log|null|target|input|length|select|error|url|context|false|trigger|max|window|success|aborted|typeof|extraData|for|clk|id|action|responseText|successful|ajaxSubmit|op||xml|true|val|attr|semantic|clk_y|call|veto|event|clk_x|callbacks|undefined|each|cb|sub|image|body|responseXML|one|tag|Array|dataType|pre|ok|multipart|documentElement|offset|setAttribute|setTimeout|plugin|fieldValue|selected|reset|disabled|isXml|els|via|getElementsByTagName|not|iframeSrc|sel|index|textarea|complete|innerHTML|ct|opera|indexOf|constructor|location|DOM|ops|timeout|timedOut|json|href|parseJSON|tagName|parsererror|ta|scr|mp|checked|ajaxForm|callback|checkbox|XMLDocument|radio|doSubmit|text|status|formToArray|new|console|selectedIndex|param|continue|method|msg|onload|clearForm|getAttribute|iframe|jmax|attributes|fileUpload|getResponseHeader|toLowerCase|extraInputs|beforeSubmit|active|resetForm|elements|in|beforeSerialize|validate|vetoed|remove|oldSuccess|upload|GET|ajaxError|serialize|try|encoding|enctype|extend|appendTo|1000px|toXml|global|beforeSend|POST|src|attachEvent|closeKeepAlive|load|domCheckCount|headers|header|detachEvent|document|contentWindow|contentDocument|fileInputs|test|content|selector|ready|bind|option|javascript|string|script|offsetX|left|ajaxFormUnbind|click|clearFields|100|pageY|top|pageX|dataFilter|isReady|arguments|httpData|postError|ActiveXObject|nodeName|css|getTime|element|_|Date|ajaxSettings|trim|match|of|object|position|jqFormIO|process|abort|setRequestHeader|aborting|ajaxStart|ajaxSend|getAllResponseHeaders|statusText|absolute|https|password|skipping|clearInputs|no|have|replaceWith|replaceTarget|html|parent|apply|find|toUpperCase|isFunction|prototype|jquery|instanceof|debug|file|get|Form|blank|must|join|about|Error|alert|ajax|enable|specified|notify|nodeType|or|formSerialize|zero|250|terminating|queuing|textContent|globalEval|found|available|throw|isDefaultPrevented|isXMLDoc|onLoad|by|catch|caught|async|loadXML|removeData|XMLDOM|Microsoft|DOMParser|ajaxStop|ajaxSuccess|jQuery|ajaxComplete|eval|parseFromString|preventDefault|requeing|unbind|addEventListener|finally|removeEventListener|hidden|parseXML|button|merge|fieldSerialize|skipEncodingOverride|removeAttr|offsetTop|offsetLeft||offsetY|closest|forceSync|is'.split('|'),0,{}));
```

Without it my wordpress slider doesn't work, but here it is regarded as a virus:
https://sucuri.net/new-malware-evalfunctionpacked.html
Thanks!

Comment: The code is explained in the link you provided.

Comment: Yes, but it's weird that without it the slider does not work..

Comment: Your code and the snippet on the linked page are not similar.

Answer (score 1):

A code being obfuscated doesn't mean that is a malware.

The methods that this script uses appears to use some ajax. It could be a security problem. Why does a slider have to make ajax requests ? So yes, take care with this script.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the right code from google here and now it is working:
http://code.google.com/p/onede4/source/browse/webapp/js/jquery.form-2.67.js?spec=svn39&r=39
It is jQuery Form Plugin * version: 2.67 (12-MAR-2011)
Thanks!